# Content is not getting displayed on printing the content inside a bootstrap modal but a blank page comes in print

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to print the contents of a bootstrap modal leaving the space for images blank on clicking the print button which is also inside the modal.

But , I am getting a blank page on clicking the print button , no contents are getting displayed.

I tried this in xamp server with PHP 5 , MySQL 5 and Apache .

## First , I have a eye icon that opens the bootstrap modal:[quote.php]

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="show_modal('<?php echo  $quote['id'] ?>','bill_model.php','quotation_modal')"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> </td>

  <div id="quotation_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> </div>
  include "footer.php"
```

## Second , is the footer.php

```
function show_modal(id, ajax_url, appednd_id) { 
      $.ajax({
         url: ajax_url + '?action=' + appednd_id,
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
            id: id
         },
         success: function(data) {
            $('#' + appednd_id).html(data);
            $('#' + appednd_id).modal('show');
         }
      });
   } 
   $('#print').on('click', function(){ window.print();  });
```

## Third is the bill_model.php:

```
<?php

   if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'quotation_modal'){ 



   $id =$_POST['id'];




   ?>


   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <div class="col-md-12 " id="bill_model">
         <div class="col-md-6 nopadding pull-left" id="logo1">
            <div class="col-md-3">  
                  <a><img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="85px"; height="100px;" > </a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-9"> 
               <h1 style="font-size: 24px;"> <span>Oth </span> <span style="color: #b29a10;">Gaaa</span> <span style="color:#008b36;"> Logis</span></h1>
               <h1 style="color: green;">Smart P </h1>
               <p style="font-size: 11px;">
              </p>
            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 nopadding pull-right" style="margin-top: 12px;" id="add1">

            <p style="font-size: 11px;">
               <b>Branch Office:</b>
              11111

            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 11px;"><b>Mob:</b> 4242424242, <b>Ph:</b> 044 - 53535 | www.example.com</p>
            <p style="font-size: 11px;"><b>GSTIN:</b> 3434342427174ZD</p>
            <p style="font-size: 11px;"><b>Pan No:</b> AAAAAAAA</p>
         </div>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <table style="width: 100%;">
               <tbody style="font-size: 10px;">
                  <tr>
                     <td rowspan="6"  style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;">



                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">Consignor  Name:</label>test</p> 

                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">Address:</label>AAAAA</p> 
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">Contact Number:</label>9999999999</p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">GSTIN:</label>EEEEEE</p>


                     </td>    
                     <td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">
                        <p><label>Bill No: </label>22222222222</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td  style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>Bill Date: </label>8/9/2001</p>

                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>Bill Branch:</label>Chennai </p>

                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>PAN NO:</label>eeeeeeeeee</p>

                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>GSTIN NO :</label>66666666666</p>
                     <p><label>State - Code :</label> TN-43</p>

                     </td> 

                  </tr>
                  <tr><td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>SAC CODE :TN</label> </p>

                     </td> 
                  </tr>

               </tbody>
              </table>
              <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive mytable">

               <table class="table table-bordered">
               <thead>


                  <tr>



                     <th>Dkt No</th>

                     <th>Date</th>

                     <th>From</th>

                     <th>To</th>

                     <th>Mode</th>



                  </tr>

               </thead>
               <tbody id="append_data">


                    <tr>

                       <td>111111</td>

                        <td>22222222</td>

                        <td>AAAAAA</td>

                        <td>SSSSSSSSSSSS</td>



                    </tr>


               </tbody>
               <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="15" rowspan="6" class="text-left"><b> Remarks </b> <br/>RRRRRRRRR</td>
                     <td>Sub Total</td>
                     <td>111111</td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td>SGST <span>3 %</span></td>

                     <td>333333333</td>



                  </tr>

                     <tr>

                     <td>CGST <span> 5 %</span></td>

                     <td>44444444444</td>



                  </tr>

                  <tr>

                     <td>IGST <span>5 %</span></td>

               <td>55555555</td>



                  </tr>

                  <tr>

                     <td>Unloading charge</td>

               <td>4</td>



                  </tr>


                  <tr>

                     <td> Halting charge</td>


                  <td>3</td>


                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="13" class="text-left"> <b>In Words :eeee only</b></td>
                     <td colspan="2">Net Payable Amount</td>
                     <td>333333</td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="10" rowspan="5">

                        <h2 class="text-left"><b>For EX</b></h2><br/>
<div style="width:100%; height:50px;"><img src="qw.jpg" align="left" width="100px" height="45px"/><br/></div>
                        <h2 class="text-left"><b>Authorized Signatory</b></h2>
                     </td>
                     <td colspan="7"> 
                        <h2><b>Terms & Condition</b></h2>
                     </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="8"><p class="text-left">1. PAYMENT WILL BE MADE AS PER PO AFTER SUBMISSION OF BILLS            </p></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td colspan="8"><p class="text-left"> 2.  CHEQUE PAYBLE IN FAVOUR OF OM GAYATRI LOGISTICS                                      </p>                </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="8"><p class="text-left">3. KINDLY MAKE THE PAYMENTYS WITHIN 15 DAYS ELSE INTEREST @24%P.A    WILL BE CHARGED ON ALL OUTSTANDING AMOUNTS.          </p></td>
                  </tr>

               </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="print" onClick="window.print();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-close"></span> Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



   }
```

On clicking the print button inside the modal , I am expecting to get the content inside the modal leaving the space for images blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done for a kind of challan form, which is inside bootstrap modal. So, what you need to do is to include this code in your `.css` file and include that `.css` file in your page or at the top of the modal's page to target your modal. It may help you.

```
/*It only prints data inside the modal when appear, specially for bank challan form*/
@media print {
@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
}
/* on modal open bootstrap adds class "modal-open" to body, so you can handle that case and hide body */
#generate_modal_pay.modal-open {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#generate_modal_pay.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
#generate_modal_pay.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
    visibility: visible; /* make visible modal body and header */
 }
}
```

And remember one thing these lines are not commented, these are the ids of bootstrap modal
    `#generate_modal_pay.modal-open` and `#generate_modal_pay.modal-open .modal .modal-header,#generate_modal_pay.modal-open .modal .modal-body`
And this `#generate_modal_pay` is the id of modal body.

But if you want all modals to be print I mean to say only it's body data, then simply add this code which will work for all modal where ever you include the `.css` file.

```
/*It only prints data inside the modal when appear, specially for bank challan form*/
@media print {
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
}
/* on modal open bootstrap adds class "modal-open" to body, so you can handle that case and hide body */
body.modal-open {
    visibility: hidden;
}

body.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
body.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
    visibility: visible; /* make visible modal body and header */
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is the modal-open class in my bootstrap modal ?

Comment: Look dear, you will have a `.css` file paste my code in that `.css` file and include the `.css` file in your page where modal is located, if not then paste my code in `<style>` tag where your modal is located. if you paste the last one code then print style will be applied to all of your modals automatically in that page. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Next you don't have to worry about the `modal-open` class, this code will do the trick.

Comment: I am getting the entire page displayed . But I need the content inside the modal alone leaving the space for images blank.

Comment: Have you applied the code correctly which I have posted for you ? If yes, then it will only give you access to print the entire modal body mean to say the content and not the whole page, after that you can do a bit change in my code to only hide the image while clicking print button.

Comment: Give a same class name to all images and then in print media code, hide the image with that class, so it won't be included....

Answer (score 0):

First , I have a eye icon that opens the bootstrap modal:[quote.php]

```
<style>
 @media screen {
    #printSection {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  @media print {
    body * {
      visibility:hidden;
    }
    #printSection, #printSection * {
      visibility:visible;
    }
    #printSection {
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      padding: 50px 0px 20px 40px;
      margin: 100px 0px 40px 100px;
    }

  }
</style>

<td><a href="#" class="view_data" id="<?php echo  $quote['id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> </td>


<div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

 <div class="modal-dialog"  style="    margin-top: -12%;">

  <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
  <div class="modal-content"  style="width: 950px; margin-left: -190px;">
    <div class="modal-header viewhead">
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center; margin-right: 305px;">Quote</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close viewclosebtn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->  
    <div class="modal-body"  style="height: 560px;  overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">

     <div class="header">
       <img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;  height: 130px;">
     </div>
     <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
       <div style="width: 15%;">
        <img src="img2.jpg" style="padding-top: 15px;  width: 105px;  height: 100%" align="left">
      </div>

      <div style="width: 85%;background: url('img3.jpg');  background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; margin-top: 15px;">
        <div id="printThis">
          <div class="msg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="cusfooter">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modcanbtn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modmailbtn"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Email</button>
    <button id="btnPrint" type="button" class="btn btn-default modpribtn"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default moddownbtn"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</button>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>



<script>
 $('.view_data').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
      url:"bill_model.php",
      method:"post",
      data:{test:id},
      success:function(data){
        $(".msg").html(data);
        $("#MyModal").modal("show");

      } 
    });

  })


document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
  }

  function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
      var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
      $printSection.id = "printSection";
      document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
  }

</script>
```

Senond is the bill_model.php

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){

echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <table style="width: 100%;">
               <tbody style="font-size: 10px;">
                  <tr>
                     <td rowspan="6"  style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;">



                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">Consignor  Name:</label>test</p> 

                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">Address:</label>AAAAA</p> 
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">Contact Number:</label>9999999999</p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;"><label style="width: 150px;">GSTIN:</label>EEEEEE</p>


                     </td>    
                     <td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">
                        <p><label>Bill No: </label>22222222222</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td  style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>Bill Date: </label>8/9/2001</p>

                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>Bill Branch:</label>Chennai </p>

                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>PAN NO:</label>eeeeeeeeee</p>

                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>GSTIN NO :</label>66666666666</p>
                     <p><label>State - Code :</label> TN-43</p>

                     </td> 

                  </tr>
                  <tr><td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 6px;text-align: left;">

                     <p><label>SAC CODE :TN</label> </p>

                     </td> 
                  </tr>

               </tbody>
              </table>
              <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive mytable">

               <table class="table table-bordered">
               <thead>


                  <tr>



                     <th>Dkt No</th>

                     <th>Date</th>

                     <th>From</th>

                     <th>To</th>

                     <th>Mode</th>



                  </tr>

               </thead>
               <tbody id="append_data">


                    <tr>

                       <td>111111</td>

                        <td>22222222</td>

                        <td>AAAAAA</td>

                        <td>SSSSSSSSSSSS</td>



                    </tr>


               </tbody>
               <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="15" rowspan="6" class="text-left"><b> Remarks </b> <br/>RRRRRRRRR</td>
                     <td>Sub Total</td>
                     <td>111111</td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td>SGST <span>3 %</span></td>

                     <td>333333333</td>



                  </tr>

                     <tr>

                     <td>CGST <span> 5 %</span></td>

                     <td>44444444444</td>



                  </tr>

                  <tr>

                     <td>IGST <span>5 %</span></td>

               <td>55555555</td>



                  </tr>

                  <tr>

                     <td>Unloading charge</td>

               <td>4</td>



                  </tr>


                  <tr>

                     <td> Halting charge</td>


                  <td>3</td>


                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="13" class="text-left"> <b>In Words :eeee only</b></td>
                     <td colspan="2">Net Payable Amount</td>
                     <td>333333</td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="10" rowspan="5">

                        <h2 class="text-left"><b>For EX</b></h2><br/>
<div style="width:100%; height:50px;"><img src="qw.jpg" align="left" width="100px" height="45px"/><br/></div>
                        <h2 class="text-left"><b>Authorized Signatory</b></h2>
                     </td>
                     <td colspan="7"> 
                        <h2><b>Terms & Condition</b></h2>
                     </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="8"><p class="text-left">1. PAYMENT WILL BE MADE AS PER PO AFTER SUBMISSION OF BILLS            </p></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                     <td colspan="8"><p class="text-left"> 2.  CHEQUE PAYBLE IN FAVOUR OF OM GAYATRI LOGISTICS                                      </p>                </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="8"><p class="text-left">3. KINDLY MAKE THE PAYMENTYS WITHIN 15 DAYS ELSE INTEREST @24%P.A    WILL BE CHARGED ON ALL OUTSTANDING AMOUNTS.          </p></td>
                  </tr>

               </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>';

}
```